# verilog Syntax error(HDLCompiler:806)

Tags: verilog

I am new to Verilog and I'm keep getting these compile errors. I've googled the error, but i didn't get an answer. Here is my code and the errors.

```
always @(*) begin
     //seed=32'habcd123cd;//assigning seed
     if(posedge axi_clk & first[0]) begin
          load_seed=1'b1;
     end

     if(load_seed) begin
          first[1]=1'b1;
     end

     if(negedge axi_clk & first[1]) begin
          load_seed=1'b0;
          first=2'b00;
     end
 end
```

My errors

> ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "K:/final project/codes/v2/input_arbiter.v" Line                     252: Syntax error near "posedge".
>   ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "K:/final project/codes/v2/input_arbiter.v" Line 258: Syntax error near "negedge".
>   ERROR:HDLCompiler:598 - "K:/final project/codes/v2/input_arbiter.v" Line 46: Module  ignored due to previous errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `posedge`/`negedge` in a wrong way. These keywords should be used in a sensitivity list of always block, e.g.:

```
always @(posedge clk)
```

or

```
always @(negedge clk)
```

`always @(*)` is used to describe combinational logic, or logic gates. What you're trying to achieve is sequential logic.

You should also know (please refer to [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/39709/using-both-edges-of-a-clock) topic) that

> when you assign to a register in an edge-sensitive always block, you're defining a flip-flop. FPGAs do not have flip-flops that can trigger on both edges of a clock. **That's why you need two separate always blocks, one for each edge of the clock**, and then figure out a way to combine the outputs of the two blocks without creating glitches.

Comment: Just a note that you can also use posedge/negedge in `initial` and other blocks for testbench code (like `initial begin ... @(posedge clk); a <= 1'b1; ...` kind of thing)

Comment: thanks for your answer.I made two always block one for the negative edge and the other for the positive edge as you said and it worked.